# Information gain for unequally sized time series

Tags: probability, entropy, information-theory, mutual-information

I have some time series data, $\mathbf{x}_{1:T} = \{ x_1, \dots, x_T \}$ where the observation at time $t$, $X_t$, is a continuous random variable. Let $Y_t$ denote a discrete random variable at time $t$ that, conditioned on the previous $t$ observations, has support over $t$ values. (It is an estimate for each of the previous time points.)

Is this mutual information well-defined?

$$
\text{MI}(Y_t, X_t) = \mathbb{H}[p(\color{red}{Y_{t-1}} \mid \mathbf{x}_{1:t-1})] - \mathbb{E}_{X_t}[p(Y_{t} \mid \mathbf{x}_{1:t-1}, X_t = x_t)].
$$

In words, I want to know how much information I gain about $Y_t$ by observing $X_t$.

I ask for two reasons:

1. The maximum entropy of a discrete distribution with support over $N$ points is a uniform distribution, so $- \sum_{n=1}^N p(x_n) \log p(x_n) = - \log 1/N = \log N$. The LHS of my equation has support over $N-1$ points; the RHS has support over $N$ points. It seems like these are on the different "scales", but I'm not sure how to handle this.
2. When I approximate $\text{MI}(X_t, Y_t)$ using some code, I get a slightly different answer (always slightly larger). And sometimes the value for $\text{MI}(Y_t, X_t)$ is negative, and I know that MI is non-negative.

Comment: information gain (mutual information) is measured from the probabilities of the data $\mathbf{x}$, not from the data itself. Probabilities as you know must sum to 1, implying two different probability distributions that have the same support would be same-sized from a probabilistic point of view regardless

Comment: Are you arguing that the mutual information I wrote above is not well-defined? The support of the LHS and RHS are different. (I agree in that case, but I don't know how people handle this scenario.)